# Convert IEnumerable<DataRow> to EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> or DataView

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How i can `result` to `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>` or `DataView`?

```
DataTable table1 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table2 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table3 = /*something*/ ;

IEnumerable<DataRow> result = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable() join 
                                    t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>("id") equals t2.Field<int>("t1id") join
                                    t3 in table3.AsEnumerable() on t2.Field<int>("t3id") equals t3.Field<int>("id")
                               where 666.Equals(t3.Field<int>("id"))
                              select t1);
```

thanks

Comment: You could use `CopyToDataTable` and go from there...

Comment: An `EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>` cannot be directly instantiated because there are no public constructors for this class ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: But `(from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable() where 666.Equals(t1.Field<int>("id")) select t1) ` return `EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>`

Comment: to Jon Skeet: table1,table2,table3 It can be modified. I do not want to constantly monitor changes and execute the code again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet said:

```
DataTable table1 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table2 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table3 = /*something*/ ;

DataTable result = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable() join 
                                    t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>("id") equals t2.Field<int>("t1id") join
                                    t3 in table3.AsEnumerable() on t2.Field<int>("t3id") equals t3.Field<int>("id")
                               where 666.Equals(t3.Field<int>("id"))
                              select t1).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

If you want a DataView:

```
DataTable table1 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table2 = /*something*/ ;
DataTable table3 = /*something*/ ;

DataView result = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable() join 
                                    t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int>("id") equals t2.Field<int>("t1id") join
                                    t3 in table3.AsEnumerable() on t2.Field<int>("t3id") equals t3.Field<int>("id")
                               where 666.Equals(t3.Field<int>("id"))
                              select t1).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>().AsDataView();
```

Comment: one more problems... **if  `result.count == 0`** then **exception**.. :((

Comment: unfortunately I had DataView update every time you change t2 :(

Answer (score 1):

From .NET Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asdataview?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTableExtensions_AsDataView__1_System_Data_EnumerableRowCollection___0__)

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<bool>("OnlineOrderFlag") == true
    orderby order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")
    select order;

DataView view = query.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```